# Robocopy occasionally "forgets" to copy files

Tags: windows, ntfs, robocopy, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I use robocopy to copy modified files between my development machine and a server.
Source machine is Windows 10. Target machine is Windows Server 2016 Standard.

This is the command and parameters I use:

```
robocopy [source_path] [destination_path] /E /Z /XD [source_path_excluded].
```

This command worked for years without any problems. For a few weeks now, this command **occasionally** forgets **some (not all)** files to be copied.

On the command line, these files are correctly displayed as "NEWER", but they are not copied (empty percentage). Other files are correctly displayed as "NEWER" and the corresponding counter increases to 100%.
After the command finishes running, I simply run it again (without any change) and the previously missing files are then copied. Occasionally this does not work until the third or fourth attempt.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

/XO option copy only newer files ,  for example, the command would be:
robocopy C:\SourceFolder D:\DestinationFolder ABC.dll /XO

On the other hand, tools like SyncThing and Gs Richcopy360 would give you good results with file-level replication from one server to another.

Comment: Thanks - but the problem is, that I *indeed* want to copy only newer files. But *sometimes* this fails.